# GroundOverlay And TimeSpan On Embedded Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Am attempting to add a ground overlay to a Google Earth embed. The ground overlay has a series of six transparent gif images -- the URLs of which are dynamically added to a KML file. Only question is -- now how do I add the ground overlay using `ge.createGroundOverlay('')` when I have no 'icon' -- it's a URL. Tried to add it using a network link, but all six images are thrown on there and there is no slider to animate them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the tutorial and code examples:
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/geometries#groundoverlay

To ensure animation works you must set the time elements of the groundOverlay: timeSpan or timeStamp. 
See https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/time

Here's snippet of code to create a ground overlay in Google Earth API with a URL:

```
// Create the GroundOverlay
var groundOverlay = ge.createGroundOverlay('');

// Specify the image path and assign it to the GroundOverlay
var icon = ge.createIcon('');
icon.setHref("http://www.google.com/logos/earthday08.gif");
groundOverlay.setIcon(icon);

var timeSpan = ge.createTimeSpan('');
timeSpan.getBegin().set('2009-01-01T17:00:00Z');
timeSpan.getEnd().set('2009-01-01T18:00:00Z');
groundOverlay.setTimePrimitive(timeSpan)

// Specify the geographic location
var latLonBox = ge.createLatLonBox('');
latLonBox.setBox(48.80, 48.75, -121.77, -121.85, 0);
groundOverlay.setLatLonBox(latLonBox);

// Add the GroundOverlay to Earth
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(groundOverlay);
```

If you're adding the GroundOverlay via a NetworkLink then the URL of the NetworkLink must be to the KML which includes the GroundOverlay and the associated URL to overlay image.
See https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/kml#kmlnetworklink

```
var link = ge.createLink('');
var href = 'http://code.google.com/'
           + 'apis/earth/documentation/samples/kml_example.kml'
link.setHref(href);

var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink('');
networkLink.set(link, true, true); // Sets the link, refreshVisibility, and flyToView

ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
```

Comment: I'm able to do both of those. What's happening is I have a series of images (radar images) that I need to animate. According to documentation found here (http://freegeographytools.com/2007/animated-gifs-in-google-earth), I should be able to do that using TimeSpan or TimeStamp. However, the documentation I have found is for how to add it to the Google Earth program, not an embedded GE. When I add using a network link, all six of my images are shown at once and I get no animation control.

Comment: Must set the time on the GroundOverlay element. See updated answer

Comment: So, icon.setHref('http://mywebsite.com/myurl.aspx'); will work as long as I give it a start and end time?

Comment: Setting icon href is independent from setting the start/end times. If don't set times then the overlay is static and will always be visible.

Comment: Tried this. It threw up the animation control, but no images. I have a feeling setting the icon's setHref variable to a KML file is not doable.

Comment: I have no problems getting a single .gif image to work on a ground overlay. The issue lies in having a ground overlay with six different images and six different timespans to overlay and animate. There has to be a way to do this. If not, then there should be.

Comment: Can you create 6 different ground overlays each with its own timespan?

Comment: That is what I'm doing, but dynamically. I'm downloading new radar images every five minutes and using the directory contents to create an ASP.NET page that spits out KML structure with six ground overlays, each with its own time stamp. In just the past few minutes, I have been able to actually get this to work, sort of. I have the animation control and I have the images. Only problem is that they are all appearing mixed together at the beginning, then as you step through the timestamps, the expired images disappear. Not exactly what I'm wanting, but closer.